# running sqlite3 script inside bash

Tags: bash, sqlite

I am trying to run multiple commands from a bash file of sqlite3 on ubuntu 15.10. The code is to pull the passwords from the user's google chrome and email it to them. I have everything but the sqlite3 part down. I'm trying to make this as simple and as easy to use for them as possible. I don't know sqlite3 and it's kicking my tail.  How would I produce a bash file using this sqlite3 code?

```
sqlite3 'Login Data'
.mode csv
.headers on
.separator ","
.output UsersPW.csv
select * from logins;
.exit
```

Comment: Please isolate and show us the complete SQLite code you want to run.  And then the question can focus on how to execute the code from a bash script.

Comment: What's the question here? How to embed that set of commands into a single-line command usable in a script?

Comment: I am trying to export the login information separated by ,. The code above, if typed one item at a time works the way I want it to, but I can't figure out how to do it in a bash.

Comment: etan reisner, I believe so. I'm new to sqlite3 and I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simple enough. Inside batch you can echo large data with << EOF structure.

```
sqlite3 'Login Data' << EOF
.mode csv 
.headers on 
.separator "," 
.output UserPW.csv 
select * from logins; 
.exit
EOF
```

This created the results I was needing.